# What does the machine learning wizard in Visual Studio do for binary classification tasks?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, ml.net, automl

I have a binary classification problem, for which I am attempting to apply ML.net in Visual Studio 2022.

Using the wizard in VS (right click on project, add, machine learning model), I achieve very good results, with an accuracy above 90 %.

However, I would like to have this all in source code instead of magic done by the wizard, so I am trying to replicate the results with the Auto ML API. I get within a couple of percentage points, but I never achieve *quite* the same accuracy as the wizard does, so I am assuming I am missing a step or two.

Here is what I am doing now:

I create a new MLContext, and use this to load data from a csv file. I have tried splitting training and test data explicitly, or let ML.net handle it, and that seems to make no difference.

I then setup column information, to handle numerical, categorical and ignored columns, in the same way that I can do in the wizard's UI. Then I create my experiment, and run it:

```
    var settings = new BinaryExperimentSettings()
    {
        MaxExperimentTimeInSeconds = 60 * 15, // Train for 15 minutes, same as in wizard
        CacheDirectoryName = null, // Skip the disk and store in-memory
    };

    BinaryClassificationExperiment experiment = context.Auto().CreateBinaryClassificationExperiment(settings);

    // Actually Train the model
    ExperimentResult<BinaryClassificationMetrics> result;
    result = experiment.Execute(trainData: trainData,
        progressHandler: new ProgressReporter(),
        columnInformation: columnInformation
    );
```

Is there something obvious that the wizard does that I am missing here? Alternatively: what can I do to improve my results?

Answer (score 1):

ModelBuilder developer here, I would say the automl part in model builder is essentially the same as BinaryExperiment. There might be slightly difference on how featurizer get created but shouldn't result to a big difference in training metric.

We can help you dig into this issue if you raise an issue in [ML.Net repo](https://github.com/dotnet/machinelearning/issues)
 and label it using AutoML.Net. Here's a few hypothesis that occurs in my mind

- AutoML.Net version less than 0.20.*
- You are actually running multi-class classification in model builder.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me :) I had version 0.20.1 of AutoML, and I'm definitely running a binary classification, since the best model ends up using LightGBMBinary. I'll try to make an issue of at the repo - thanks.